# Using const_cast to ignore volatile?

Tags: c++, volatile, const-cast

The `const_cast` can also be used to ignore the fact an object is `volatile`. However, what does this actually mean?? I cannot think of an example where you would use a `const_cast` on a `volatile` variable??

Comment: To pass argument to function as `pthread_create` (and then restore back the cv qualifier).

Answer (score 2):

**Never** ignore the fact that a variable is `volatile`, `const` or the like.

Doing so leads to [**Undefined Behavior**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984).

What `const_cast` allows though, is making the compiler assume that the object you cast *is not actually thus qualified*, even though the pointer / reference you have says so.
The penalty for lying to the compiler is, as always, UB.

A common example is defining a class with both qualified and nonqualified member-functions to enable const/volatile-correctess, the unqualified versions being inline-wrappers around the qualified versions which do all the work.

`volatile`is quite rare outside low-level driver / micro-controller code though.

Comment: If the `const`-qualified versions are supposed to do exactly the same thing as the non-`const`-qualified versions, then it'd make more sense to me to make the unqualified versions wrappers around the qualified versions (this can also use `const_cast`), to let the compiler detect anything that requires a non-`const` object.

Comment: @hvd: You are right, because of safety. Someone would screw it up (most likely me).

Answer (score 0):

If a variable has been declared volatile (or, indeed, const) then using `const_cast` to remove it is undefined behaviour, and a very bad idea.

But it can happen that you are given a volatile (or const) reference to something you know isn't really. In that case it is legitimate, and occasionally useful, to use `const_cast` to get back to the original.

I've done this occasionally with const, but I can't recall ever doing so with volatile. Buy then I rarely use volatile anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator The standard says, "If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through the use of a glvalue with a non-volatile-qualified type, the program behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Deduplicator So I think actually this would be UB even though there is no *access*: `volatile int x; int& r = const_cast<int&>(x);`

Comment: @Brian: "What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined. If an
attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through the use of a glvalue with
a non-volatile-qualified type, the program behavior is undefined." The first part of that paragraph is critical.

Comment: @Brian I think you're commenting on the wrong answer. FWIW I agree with your first comment. I don't have my copy of the standard to hand to be able to evaluate your second comment.

Comment: @Deduplicator had a comment here earlier, but deleted it.

Comment: @Deduplicator The second sentence doesn't say you get UB when you *access* the object; it says you get UB when you *refer* to it.

Comment: @Brian: And *refer* is used as a synonym to *access*, so all is OK. I quoted the whole paragraph so you see the context.

Comment: @Deduplicator Are you sure? Since they mention glvalues, I assumed they meant "refer" in the glvalue sense and not as a synonym for "access", *i.e.*, if at any point you produce a glvalue whose address is the address of the object, then you have a glvalue referring to that object.